# delete deployed report ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

Is there a way that reports can be automatically deleted from folders on the SSRS site when the report no longer exists in the project?

I created a solution in Data Tools that contains 10 projects. Each project contains a number of reports and deploys to its own folder on the SSRS site. In Data Tools, when I move a report from one project to another and deploy the solution, the report I moved shows up in folder / project I moved it to on the web site. However, the report also still exists in the old folder on the site even though it no longer exists in the project.

I had expected that deploying a project would remove any reports in a folder that are no longer part of the project.

Is there an option for this or do I need to manually clean up the folders on the SSRS site?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to do this. If you have a lot of changes,. the simplest way (although it might not be ideal in your scenario) is to delete all the folders on the server side and then just redeploy everything again.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to do this. If you have a lot of changes,. the simplest way (although it might not be ideal in your scenario) is to delete all the folders on the server side and then just redeploy everything again. – Alan Schofield Sep 27 '17 at 21:31